# I get a transparent/empty image with Mapnik in python from a raster file

Tags: python, raster, tiles, mapnik

1. I start by selecting a raster from the website of the Swiss Federal Office.
   Therefore, I know, with certainty, the projection in which this layer is located.

Source : https://shop.swisstopo.admin.ch/en/products/height_models/alti3D
-> instructions: click on 'read more', 'sample data' and 'TIF + TFW'.

2. Then I write the xml file defining the rendering of my layer as below :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Map  background-color='#00000000' srs="+init=epsg:4326">
  <Style name="generalMapStyle">
    <Rule>
        <RasterSymbolizer>
            <stop value = "0"/>
            <stop color="red" value = "25"/>
            <stop color="red" value = "500"/>
        </RasterSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
  </Style>
  <Layer name="Any raster" srs="+init=epsg:2056">
    <StyleName>generalMapStyle</StyleName>
    <Datasource>
      <Parameter name="file">rater_file.tif</Parameter>
      <Parameter name="type">raster</Parameter>
    </Datasource>
  </Layer>
</Map>
```

3. Finally, I launch the python program below:

```
import mapnik

m = mapnik.Map(256, 256)
mapnik.load_map(m, "stylesheet.xml")
m.zoom_all()
mapnik.render_to_file(m, "map_xml.png")
```

4. I obtain in return a png file containing only a transparent layer.

Can someone please help me to figure out what's going wrong?
Feel free to share others tools for map rendering in Python.